# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' ROBOFLOW object object detection

Tags: python, object, detection, roboflow

[image]

I created a dataset by roboflow, I'm trying to use it but there is an error.

in get_conditional_configuration_variable
default=os.getenv("HOME") + "/.config/roboflow/config.json",
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images of code

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was using this:

```
pip install roboflow==0.2.34
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an environment variable (Windows command line environment variable) `HOME` to your home folder (e.g. `c:\user\my_name`).

If there is no `HOME` environment variable you get the error.